# Best Delphi freeware compiler in user friendliness

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am working on a C++/Win32 project, and I have some Delphi code from some other (not mine) project that is relevant, and I want to convert it to C++ and integrate into my project.

Keep in mind I have no experience with Delphi.

What's a good and user-friendly Delphi complier? I don't mind about command line or GUI, as long as it's clear to use.

Comment: What you're looking for is an Object Pascal compiler with Delphi dialect, I take ?

Comment: Delphi is a commercial product.  There are zero freeware Delphi compilers.  There are however Pascal compilers that understand parts of Delphi syntax, but not all of it, and certainly not that are compatible with the DFM forms and the components inside those, which are a core part of the Delphi language and platform. There are certainly none which will build source code for a complete app originally written "in Delphi".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only Delphi compiler is the Delphi compiler. It's not free. There is the Free Pascal Compiler, FPC. That is, as its name suggests, free. FPC can compile most Delphi code but be aware that many Delphi libraries, e.g. the VCL, are not available for FPC.

Comment: Conclusion: the Delphi compiler is the "Best Delphi compiler in user friendliness".

Comment: Hopefully not as picky about its friends as Linux told to be ? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this would be too painful for you you to convert the source code in C++ manually.

But have you tried [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/)? It is intended to be an open source equivalent of Delphi.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Lazarus is an just an IDE to FPC :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The Lazarus is a bit more than "just an IDE for FPC", it comes with LCL which is somewhat equivalent to delphi VCL.

Comment: well, yes, but i was comparing this answer from previous. After FPC was mentioned there might be some sense in mentioning Virtual Pascal or GNU Pascal or OpenSybil/WDSybil. But in this context, pascal compilers, Lazarus is kind of "some package with FPC included" moniker.

Answer (score 0):

The previous responses here were all valid in 2012, but things have changed.

Nowadays there is a free (as in beer) Community Edition:
https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/starter/free-download